# code inside ref once not executing angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

***Code inside the this.verifyUserToken block of does not execute***. I guess it has to do with asynchronous calls being that the data returned is not ready but I seem not to know how to go about it.

```
this.verifyUserToken = function(){
            //Check if token matches existing token and if verified is true
            ref.orderByChild('token').equalTo(this.token).once('value').
            then(function(dataSnapshot){
                //If token matches
                    if(dataSnapshot.val()){
                        alert("Token Exists",dataSnapshot.val().token);
                        $scope.isVerified = "YES";
                    }else{
                        alert("Token does not exist",dataSnapshot.val());
                        $scope.isVerified = "NO";
                    }
            });
        }

this.registerUser = function(){
            console.log("Entered registerUser()");

            this.verifyUserToken();
            alert("The Value of isVerified:"+ $scope.isVerified);
            if($scope.isVerified == "YES"){
                    alert("Verifying User Token...",this.verifyUserToken());
                    $scope.auth.$createUser({
                    "email": this.email,
                    "password" : this.password
                }).then(function(userData){
                    alert("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
                    //redirect to /userlogin if registration is successful
                    //this.changeVerifiedStatus();
                    alert("User verifed and changed");
                    $location.path('/userlogin');
                }).catch(function(error){
                    alert("Error Creating User:",error);
                });
            }else{
                alert("Token failed verification");
            }   
            };
```

Comment: You need to put the verification in then callback of your verifyUserToken. as right now it will continue isVerified will always be null

Comment: let me know if my answer works for you or if you still have any doubts. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `verifyUserToken` has a assync call to firebase you can handle it returning a `Promise` from this function and proceed with your `registerUser` only after having ther verify call finished.

I've set a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/10/) so you can see it working.

```
this.verifyUserToken = function(){
  //Check if token matches existing token and if verified is true
  var verifyUserTokenPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){                                               
    ref.orderByChild('token').equalTo(this.token).once('value').then(function(dataSnapshot){
      //If token matches
          if(dataSnapshot.val()){
              alert("Token Exists",dataSnapshot.val().token);
              $scope.isVerified = "YES";
          }else{
              alert("Token does not exist",dataSnapshot.val());
              $scope.isVerified = "NO";
          }
          //resolve the promise. you can pass any data here
          resolve($scope.isVerified);
    });
  });
  return verifyUserTokenPromise;
};

this.registerUser = function(){
  console.log("Entered registerUser()");

  this.verifyUserToken().then(function(result){
    alert("The Value of isVerified:"+ $scope.isVerified);
    if($scope.isVerified == "YES"){
            alert("Verifying User Token...",this.verifyUserToken());
            $scope.auth.$createUser({
            "email": this.email,
            "password" : this.password
        }).then(function(userData){
            alert("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
            //redirect to /userlogin if registration is successful
            //this.changeVerifiedStatus();
            alert("User verifed and changed");
            $location.path('/userlogin');
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert("Error Creating User:",error);
        });
    }else{
        alert("Token failed verification");
    }   
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks @adolfosrs, I have made the corrections, however I am now faced with an entirely different error. **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined**. Kindly help out

Comment: @user1841445 In your code you were using `this.token` and I changed to `token` for testing porposes try to roll it back for your original one. You didn't include where was this information coming from so this will depends on your implementation.

Comment: I already replaced `token` with `this.token`. The error is from this line `ref.orderByChild('token').equalTo(this.token).once('value').then(function(dataSnapshot){...`

Comment: @user1841445 do you have the user token?

Comment: I have finally been able to fix the error. I realized that all variables defined `this.variable_name` returned **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'variable_name' of undefined.** Had to resolve same issues for `email` and `password` variables. I fixed this declaring them at the `$scope` level. however, I will like to know why `this.variable_name` returns **undefined**

Comment: @user1841445 glad that you made some progress! Again the usage of the `this` will depends on your implementation. This is in the core of javascript, if you want to understand how `this` behave you can start reading [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Let me know if you still have any doubts and if not could you please accept the answer? Thank you.

Comment: already accepted the answer. I have a less than 15 post score. Thanks a lot. I'm new to angularjs and firebase. Learning has been quite challenging but interesting.

Comment: @user1841445 You welcome. Keep asking if you have any other doubts. We are here to help.